# PDFlib 8 - how to change the PDF Output from pdf 1.7 to 1.4

Tags: pdflib

We are using a pdflib 8 server - and the standard output is a pdf 1.7 (PDF/A-2) format...

but our customer needs a pdf in a 1.4 (PDF/A-1) format.
The original PDF template is done in a pdf 1.4 format.

I 'm new to the pdflib server, so I have no idea, where i can change the output format from pdf 1.7 to pdf 1.4.

I'm looking for a xml / properties file to change that value!

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Patching the byte [7] of "%PDF-1.7" from '7' (0x37) to '4' (0x34) might, just might work, as the template is in 1.4. Dangerous.

Comment: you mean after it is rendered by the pdflib server? That's not possible. I'm more looking for a properties file, but I can't find anything!

Answer (score 2):

Please try following

```
p.begin_document(outfile, "compatibility=1.4")
```